# What does it mean "In case the PHP file is outside the document root, only its directory is scanned"?

Tags: php, php-ini

I am reading about the php.ini file reading flow. I have read about it on the php.net website, but one thing that I can't understand is at the end of second paragraph on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php), which says that

```
In case the PHP file is outside the document root, only its directory is scanned
```

What does this mean?

Comment: that is quite clear: when you call a php file it searches automatically for .ini files (configuration) in the php file's folder, but also in all the parent directories up to the ROOT. But of course, if the file is outside the ROOT hierarchy, it doesnt scan there, and processes only the file's folder

Comment: You mean that if no ini file is found in the root then the server will scanned only the directory where the php.ini file is placed (as set by default on the server) ?

Comment: no, every .ini file will be scanned between the file's directory up to the root. It doesn't really search for a particular ini file, if there is one, it is scanned, if there are several, they are all scanned. But of course, if the file folder is outside the folder hierarchy of the server root, he doesn't walk the folder's hierarchy, he wouldn't know where to stop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify a couple of things in addition to [Julian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7118634/julian)'s answer.

The default php.ini file for the server (e.g. `/path/to/default/ini/php.ini`) will *always* be scanned, no matter where the PHP file itself is located. What happens after that depends on whether the PHP file is stored in the document root path or not.

## In Document Root Path

Say you have a PHP file saved at `/path/to/doc/root/another/dir/file.php`.

The server will look for an ini file in the following directories:

- `/path/to/root/another/dir`
- `/path/to/root/another`
- `/path/to/root`

If an ini file is found in any of those locations, they will be scanned *as well* as the default ini file.

## Outside Document Root Path

Say you have a PHP file saved at `/path/outside/doc/root/file.php`.

The server will look in the following directory:

- `/path/outside/doc/root`

If an ini file is found in this location (i.e. `/path/outside/doc/root/php.ini`), it will be scanned *as well* as the default ini file.

Comment: Great answer. 

**In both cases server’s default ini file will be loaded**

If the requested php file is **outside the root directory** then the ini file will be only scan in that directory, not in parent or elsewhere.

If the requested php file is **inside the root directory** then the ini file will be first scan at the folder where the requested php file is located and will still scan for ini file in up level (parent) directory till the root.

Comment: @SunnyKhan yep, you got it! :)

Comment: One thing more i want to ask that **php.ini** is only read in two cases. 1) When the server starts up. 2) When the cgi script is executed on the request data. Is i am correct ?

Comment: @SunnyKhan I'm not too sure on that sorry I've only used PHP as an apache module, never as CGI. The page linked in your question has an ini directive `user_ini.cache_ttl - controls how often user INI files are re-read` which suggests the user ini files are loaded when the relevant PHP file is accessed, and the ini file is cached for however long is set by the directive (default 300 seconds). If a PHP file is accessed that uses the same ini file (not necessarily the same PHP file, could be another PHP file in same directory) it will load the ini file from cache instead. I could be wrong though!

Comment: @SunnyKhan AFAIK, the server default ini file is only loaded when the server is (re)started though.

Comment: Thanks many time :). Will you be connected on Facebook with me ?
Kindly share your profile link.

Comment: And what about the custom php.ini files. Are they loaded on each request to the server ?

Comment: @SunnyKhan sorry this isn't a place for getting Facebook contacts. As for the custom php.ini files, I assume you mean the user ini files described on the page you linked? In which case, if you look at my previous comment it describes how they are cached for a certain period of time, but as I said, I don't use PHP CGI so I can't be 100% sure of how it works sorry!

Answer (score 1):

When the PHP file is outside of the document root (so if the file is not in the document root (=the root where you place the files for your website)), only the directory where the file is in will be scanned.

So they will start with the folder of the specific PHP file and then they just scan every folder by going a folder up every time until the document root. If the file isn't in the document root they are only checking the directory of where the file is in.

So there are two options:

**1. File is in root directory**
or
**2. File is not in root directory**

If the file is in the root directory: than they will search for an .ini file starting in the directory of the php file which is called. Than they keep searching and scanning by going up every time until the document root.

If the file isn't in the root directory: than they will search for an .ini file ONLY in the directory of the php file which is called.

Comment: You mean that if no ini file is found in the root then the server will scanned only the directory where the php.ini file is placed (as set by default on the server) ?

Comment: No. If you use (call) a php file it searches for a configuration file (.ini). It searches in the directory of the file and in the parent directories until the document root. If the php file isn't in the document root file tree, it only scans the directory of the php file.

Comment: So it isn't about no ini file found, but it is about 'searching' an .ini file when calling a php file and where they 'search'

Comment: As you say that it searches for ini file first on that folder where the file is requested and working its way up to web root. And if no ini file is found in the tree (inside the root) then it searches the ini file in the folder where the file is requested. So what nonsense this search flow is. It already searched for the ini file on that folder where the requested page exist, then why it again searches for ini file on that folder again where the requested page exist.

Comment: The first sentence of your comment is correct. After that we have a misunderstanding. It is not about if there is no ini file found it searches it in the folder where the file is requested. I will edit my answer to explain it more clearly.

Comment: And if i understand clearly then you will got a beautiful green Tick ;)

Comment: Great !!!! I understand. Only one thing more. And if there is no ini file exist (nor in any directory nor in the root) then what will happen? Will they use the server's default php.ini file ??

Comment: Poeh, I don't really know. Think it will use the server default php.ini file. @SunnyKhan

Comment: @SunnyKhan - on the page you linked in the question, it says `In addition to the main php.ini file`. So yes, it does use the server's default php.ini file

Comment: @crazyloonybin - You got me. These above guys didn't understand my question and answered inverse as i want. I simply know that server will search for ini file from the place where the php page is requested and will go up to root. If any .ini file is found in the tree or inside the root then it will use it other wise if any ini file is not found in the tree and also not in the root then what will happen ? That was my question.

Comment: @SunnyKhan then nothing happens. The page you linked to says that it searches through that tree, `in addition to the main php.ini file`. So it will always load the default php.ini file for the server. If it finds other ini files in the tree, it will load those _as well_, otherwise it is only the server default that gets loaded.

Comment: One thing i didn't understand that why they says that **In case the PHP file is outside the document root, only its directory is scanned**, which directory they are talking about in this sentence **only its directory is scanned**?

Comment: @SunnyKhan that is talking about the directory where the PHP file itself is located. E.g. if you had the file `/path/outside/doc/root/file.php`, the directory it's talking about would be `/path/outside/doc/root`

Comment: You mean where the php requested file itself is located ?

Comment: @SunnyKhan I've added a new answer which hopefully clarifies things for you